# Code for fitting multivariate t distribution (ECME)

Tags: expectation-maximization, t-distribution

I am looking to fit some data with central multivariate t distributions.

I understand an ECME algorithm is the most promising way to do this. I wondered if anyone knew of any existing code for fitting t distributions with ECME that would get me started (in any language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't easily find anything for MATLAB (probably there are functions in R), so I wrote one: [tdistfit](https://github.com/robince/tdistfit)

Just adding it here to close the question and in case it might be useful to anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a late answer, but since I had the same question recently and couldn't find Python code to do this, I also wrote this up using the EM algorithm: [t.py](https://gist.github.com/cdipaolo/9dd6794a4f0a2889ef60a5effa419093)

Hopefully this will be useful to someone in the future.